# Replace CSS after compare today's date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this block of JS code that generates date dynamically in table cells.

```
'<td class="dateStyleBlue" data="date"><span id = "' 
+ customers.ProductID + 'date">' + util.utility( customers.GetDate) 
+ '</span></td>'
```

Current CSS

```
.dateStyleBlue{
    color: blue;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

New CSS style

```
.dateStyleRed{
    color: red;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

I want to replace the Current CSS class with the New CSS if the date is past today.

so here is what I have so far,

```
    var today = new Date();

    if (customer.GetDate < today) {
       $(dateStyleBlue).replaceWith(dateStyleRed);    
    }
```

Comment: You're missing something here `.util.utility`

Comment: Missing tag. There is a `</a>` tag without opener

Comment: What do you expect `customer.GetDate` to do?

Comment: it returns date from data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do a removeClass and a addClass.

```
 if (customer.GetDate < today) {
       $('.dateStyleBlue').removeClass('dateStyleBlue').addClass('dateStyleRed');    
 }
```

Don't forget to use the dot ( . ) to select a class and it need to be a string unless it's a javascript variable.

**EDIT**

You should be more specific with your selector because the code above will change every elements with the class `dateStyleBlue`

Comment: yes it returns date but it doesn't work some reason..do i need to put this new code below the <td> block of code?

Answer (score 0):

First I would give your  another class to reference by, say "table_row".

Then when you want to switch classes use the following code.

```
$(".table_row").removeClass("dateStyleBlue");
$(".table_row").addClass("dateStyleRed");
```

Remember to use the dot to reference by class!

Comment: @user1781367 It's required.

Comment: but it doesn't work i tried already..that's the reason I posted here

Comment: Sorry, replaceWith didn't work as I expected, try the new code above.